# Name for irregular convex octahedron with 6 vertices and consisting of two sets of 4 identical isosceles triangles

Tags: symmetry, polyhedra

I wonder if there is a name for a irregular convex octahedron, with 6 vertices, that consist of two sets of 4 identical isosceles triangles. It could be created by intersecting two rhombic prisms, or by stretching the square base of a regular octahedron into a rectangle.

Forms like these can be seen on natural orthorhombic crystals like topaz. See the images.

[image][image]

Comment: It is an... octahedron. If you want to insist on the particular properties, you might qualify it as *right isoceles*. (The crystal class of topaz is bipyramidal.)

Answer (score 0):

I would call it a rectangular bipyramid (the comment pointing out that it is an octahedron is correct; anything with 8 faces can be referred to as an octahedron, including things like [Dürer's solid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DuerersSolid.html). But, I generally associate "octahedron" with *the* regular octahedron).

A [blank] bipyramid is the shape obtained by gluing the bases of two [blank] pyramids together. So a regular octahedron is a square bipyramid; the classic Sims [plumbob](http://sims.wikia.com/wiki/Plumbob) is a (regular) hexagonal bipyramid, and so on.